# How can I straighten up a leaning vinyl fence gate?

Tags: gates

My vinyl fence gate is leaning. Not sure how to correct the problem. The panels are good just the vehicle gate is leaning. How do I correct this.
Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info; would you add some pictures or  perhaps a diagram to your question? Thanks.

Comment: Is it the gate sagging or its support?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally for a gate to lean (face is not vertical,) the post it's connected to is leaning, or its hinges have moved.

As such, re-setting the post or repositioning the hinges may be required, depending what the root cause is.

If the gate is sagging (face is vertical, but the free end is much lower than the hinged end) there is an additional possible fix, which is to run a support wire from as high as possible on the hinge post to the free end of the gate - usually this wire will incorporate a turnbuckle to allow it to be adjusted to pull the free end of the gate up until it's level.